# Combining images into one image results in OutofMemory error

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image, android-memory

I am having the user retrieve 4 images from their gallery and after each one is selected, I draw it to a canvas and then compresses the images into on image.

This is how I store the retrieved images (it is done up to four times):

```
if (mImageIndex == 0) {
    bmImages[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
    mImageSelected = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Image One Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This is how I combine my Images:

```
result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmImages[0].getWidth() * 2, bmImages[0].getHeight() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
Paint paint = new Paint();
for (int i = 0; i < bmImages.length; i++) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmImages[i], bmImages[i].getWidth() * (i % 2), bmImages[i].getHeight() * (i / 2), paint);
    bmImages[i].recycle();
}
```

It works just fine on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4, but I get an OutofMemory error on my Samsung Note 5, it says that it was trying to use 256,000,000 out of 12,000,000.

Here is my error:

```
12-08 10:06:41.021 31308-31308/com.jaymalabs.pic E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 253956108 byte allocation with 12059120 free bytes and 11MB until OOM
12-08 10:06:41.021 31308-31308/com.jaymalabs.pic E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
```

It happens when trying to create my bitmap at this line:

```
result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmImages[0].getWidth() * 2, bmImages[0].getHeight() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

How can I combine images without using a lot of memory?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. This would include the code that you are using to "retrieve 4 images from their gallery and after each one is selected, I draw it to a canvas and then compresses the images into on image". This would also include the complete stack trace showing your `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Sorry.  I've updated it with more info.  I've also tried using 'Bitmap.Config.RGB_565' and I still get OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I combing images without using a lot of memory?

Use smaller images. You are trying to assemble a roughly 8000 x 8000 pixel image. That is much too big for the Java heap.

You are welcome to try moving your code to create this bitmap into C/C++ using the NDK. I still expect you to crash on some devices, as you are trying to use ~256MB of system RAM just for this bitmap, and requesting that may have dire effects on low-end Android devices.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure about using the NDK, I don't have any experience with that.  But you were spot on, my images were too large.  I ended up scaling them down and then saving them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up scaling down my images in half before saving them to a bitmap.  This is what I used:

```
            pictureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pictureBitmap , pictureBitmap.getWidth()/2, pictureBitmap.getHeight()/2,true);
            pictureBitmap.recycle();
            bmImages[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), null, true);
```